# causing jetty exception when using cusotm webdefault.xml

Tags: windows, jetty, illegalargumentexception

I am facing the following exception when I am trying to access a war file deployed over http adapter. We are using jetty 6_1_8 for that.

Here are the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:458)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:145)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:978)
```

I have seen in other thread that the solution is set extractWar to true but in my case I have set the webAppContext.setExtractWAR(true);

I did not set in some xml file but directly in the java code. Even then I am facing the same issue.

When I dont use custom webdefault.xml it works fine.

Please help!

Comment: can you post the java code, also, you are using 6.1.8 or 8.1.6?  jetty 6 is ancient.

Comment: we are using jetty 6.1.8, its a big application where the entire code is scattered around different classes so posting code will be difficult. and also everything works fine in linux and the only problem is with windows.

Comment: if it is windows only then my vote is on case sensitivity in some filename, perhaps the name of the war?

Comment: the path is proper, also the exception is thrown in WebAppClassLoader class of jetty _parent.getResource(name). This name is the path of webdefault.xml. In some other thread I have seen the similar problem where they have mentioned that set extract to true to resolve the issue but i have tried that as well but didn't work. Is the resolution around that area?

Comment: there is precious little to go on here, that exception gives no indication what part of jetty is trying to load that resource, or even if it is jetty trying to load it.  that it apparently works correctly on linux points to a windowism which are typically related to either file locking or case insensitivity, hallmarks of windows filesystems

Comment: The issue is while getting the resource (custom webdefault.xml) as when I don't use custom webdefault.xml and use jetty provided webdefault.xml it works fine even in windows. So the problem is with getResource(<webdefault.xml path>). I am not sure why it is giving illegalargumentexception:name. regarding file locking problem I have tried useFileMappedBuffer=false in my custom webdefault.xml which didn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java.html

That seems to indicate it is a bad path reference to the provided webdefault.xml, sort that out and you should be in good shape.

Comment: I have checked this path, by creating File object and saw that the file exist.

Comment: as a file sure, but as a URL? this is the code in the URLClassPath that is having issues. url = new URL(base, ParseUtil.encodePath(name, false));

Comment: How to sort that out, I didn't get that can you please explain

Comment: meaning that whatever url going into there is not valid, hence the terrible 'name' exception coming out of UrlClassPath

Comment: ok The name is (E:\DEV_E\install_524_mssql_2008\install\noapp\etc\webdefault.xml) for windows and /ais_local/share/alodha/52/gis_CATA_5241_18000/platform_core/install/noapp/etc/webdefault.xml for linux. Note it works in linux but not for windows. Do you mean that "name" for windows should be file://<complete path as mentioned above for windows> to make it a valid url?

Comment: probably file:///E but yeah, something is up with windows paths I suspect